# Calculate distance of points along a route QGIS

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, distance, linear-referencing, gvsig

I have a line layer and a point layer, I need the **distance between the first and the last point measured along the line**.

How can I do that using QGIS? Do I need to know linear reference? I don't have any knowledge on PostGIS.

Comment: Is the data stored in a PostGIS database?

Comment: No, it isn't. The data is on shapefile format.

Comment: Oh, I see. Are the lines crossing the points? the points should be also vertexes of the line right?

Comment: In fact, the points are near to the line, but they aren't connected or crossed by it. But, yeah, the points should be vertexes of the line.   The lines are routes and the points are bus stops, and I want to mesure the distance of the bus stops along the route.

Comment: I don't see your process. Do you have a common attribute to dissolve your lines and then get the biggest distance along the line between two points that intersect the line?

Comment: Nope, I have a line which essentially it has the route name and the longitud, and I also have the bus stop, which it has is own code. The problem is: the points aren't connected to the bus route. The points **sholud be connected to the line as a network** and the get the distance between points, but along the route. And I want to solve this with a open source software.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the new LRS plugin to QGIS 2.0: http://blazek.github.io/lrs/ . The plugin uses a tolerance (you can define) between the line and each point. I think this tool solve your problem.

Comment: wow, it looks this work very well, and is exactly what I need. I'll try to learn how to use it.